# Maintaining State Between HTML page and PHP Server Page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am designing a simple drag and drop quiz. We are limiting the number of attempts to get a correct answer to two for each box/answer. However, I'd like to keep the functionality and state of the quiz separate from the display/view. 
Currently, as the user attempts to get a correct answer by dropping an answer box on top of a question box, an ajax call is made to a PHP page which returns a 'true' or 'false' value.
We have been evaluating if we want to use Session variables on the PHP page, cookies, or something even more simple to track how many attempts each box has consumed. It would be preferable (for good form's sake) to somehow maintain the state of this data on the server - so the client has no idea what is going on. Session variables seemed to make sense to me - as the user continues to make attempts with different question/answer combos, the server tracks the number of tries and returns (in the ajax response) the result of a user's question (right/wrong, and how many tries that answer has remaining, if any) but I'm wondering if there's a better solution. Any input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session seems like a good fit to me.  Cookies can be tampered with so I would avoid that if you need the error count to be accurate.

Comment: So if I am deploying this code to for example 10 students, will the server run into issues if two students are working on the quiz at the same time? Or are session variables uniquely stored for each client that is logged on? So, if Joe has tried box 1 twice, will Bill's box 1 also show up as having been tried twice?

Comment: @SpencerAllenGardner - Session is at the user level; session data for one user will not be available by another user.  This is done by creating a unique id for each user (the PHP libraries should take care of that for you). Usually the id is stored in a cookie, but, it can be included as a parameter in the HTTP request as well.

Comment: As far as the best practice from a quasi-MVC standpoint: would returning some XML/JSON with the number of attempts for that certain box be best? Or would it be even better and more clean to return a 'true' or 'false' value to determine if the box can be attempted again? I'm guessing the latter.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're not using https, and the students are in the same local network, it's fairly trivial for one of them to sniff out the cookies of another student, get the value of his/her PHPSESSID cookie and manually set the value of his/her own session cookie to it. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking

Comment: @SpencerAllenGardner - You need to return more than true or false, correct?  It sounds like you want to return whether the answer was correct (true/false) and the number or a boolean on whether or not the user has more remaining attempts; this way you can update the UI to tell them they don't have any more attempts remaining.  I would use JSON, but, the data format is up to you.

Comment: Yes - you're right - but I mean for the actual piece of data referring to a particular box's ability to continue to move, I am wondering if I should return a 'true' value, or a 'number of tries left' value. The latter seems a little messy because I'll be having to do checking within the Javascript rather than having the server take care of that.

Comment: @SpencerAllenGardner - It depends what you need to do.  Do you want to tell the user how many tries they have left?  If so, then you should return a numeric value.  With either solution you will need server-side logic to maintain the number of tries a user has left and you will also need Javascript to update the UI. From my viewpoint it makes little difference which datatype you use.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions is probably your best bet.  Cookies could be used as well, or if you can guarantee availability of HTML5 localStorage in the browser, you could use that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately to keep the functionality separate, there is not. You can use a session variable, or database storage paired with a session id stored in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Store current user state into session (temporary storage) and track what he have answered what not etc. at the last step store data into database, or file (permanent storage). Session is individual for every user. Users can't alter your site sessions.

[Session usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)